# Start exe as devenv command

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, devenv

Can we start visual studio using an external exe as a devenv command?
As described in the link: [/Command (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sf6kk3.aspx)

I am trying something in the lines of

```
devenv.exe /command "vstest.console.exe MyVSUITest.dll"
```

But this says 'Command is not valid'. Do I have to add this as Visual Studio command somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your vstest as an external tool (VS menu **Tools** - **External Tools**) and then use command name **Tools.ExternalCommand#** to start it.

Comment: Hi, I tried that. Do you know if the number of the external command is counted from top to bottom on the list starting from 1?
And it keeps complaining 'does not accept argument'. Check that the exe I am passing needs an argument.